# What "growl" type notification windows are available for WPF (windows that appear and fade after X seconds)?

Tags: c#, wpf, growl

I wanted to know if there are any good "growl" type notification windows available as open source or guided tutorials for WPF applications.  I'm looking for a window that can appear when users save for example, notifying them that the save was successful and then disappears after X seconds (with a fade out) without the user needing to take the explicit action to close the notification window.  This way for messages/notifications that require no confirmation, like the example, the user would not have to click "OK" to make the messagebox or dialog close.

Answer (score 3):

This link could help you:

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/wpf_notifyicon.aspx

It is a Pure WPF implementation of the NotifyIcon class from WinForms and supports almost everything normal WPF controls do :)

Cheers

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you use [GrowlForWindows](http://www.growlforwindows.com/gfw/default.aspx)?

You can use [C# or VB](http://www.growlforwindows.com/gfw/developers.aspx).